# topological space is called $k$- space

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called $T_B$ if every compact subset is closed.

Let $X$ be  $T_B$ and $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ be one-point compatification of $X$.

A topological space is called $k$- space if it has the property that any sunset $F$ s.t $F \cap K$ is closed for all closed compact $K$ is itself closed.

**Does the bellow theorem hold:**

> **Let $X$ be $k$- space. If $X$ is $T_B$, then $X^*$ is $T_B$.**

Comment: sunset... Nice typo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X^*$. If $\infty\notin K$, then $K$ is a compact subset of $X$; $X$ is $T_B$, so $K$ is closed in $X$ and therefore closed in $X^*$ as well, so suppose that $\infty\in K$.

Let $F=K\cap X=K\setminus\{\infty\}$, and suppose that $C$ is a compact subset of $X$. Then $C$ is closed in $X$ and hence also in $X^*$, so $K\cap C$ is a closed subset of the compact set $K$ and is therefore compact. But $F\cap C=K\cap C$, so $F\cap C$ is a compact subset of $X$ and is therefore closed in $X$. In other words, $F\cap C$ is closed in $X$ for each compact $C\subseteq X$, and $X$ is a $k$-space, so $F$ is closed in $X$. Let $U=X\setminus F$; then $U$ is open in $X$, so $U$ is open in $X^*$, and $K=X^*\setminus U$ is closed in $X^*$.

Comment: (1) Is $K∩C$  a compact set in $X^*$?

Comment: @Ebi: Of course: it’s a closed subset of $K$, and $K$ is compact.

Comment: We don't know that $ C$ is closed in $X^*$, how does $K \cap C$ closed in $X^*$?

Comment: @Ebi: We do know that $C$ is closed in $X^*$: it’s a compact, closed subset of $X$, so $X^*\setminus C$ is open in $X^*$, and $C$ is therefore closed in $X^*$.

Comment: Excuse me.I wrote my previous comment, " **We don't know that K is closed in $X^∗$, how does $K∩C$ closed in $X^∗$**"?

Comment: @Ebi: I’ve explained twice already. $K$ is compact. $C$ is compact in $X$, therefore closed in $X$, therefore closed in $X^*$. $K\cap C$ is therefore closed in the compact set $K$, so $K\cap C$ is compact. $K\cap C$ is a subset of $X$, and $X$ is $T_B$, so $K\cap C$ is closed in $X$. Therefore $K\cap C$ is closed in $X^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Say $C$ is compact in $X^*$. Remember that, by definition, **compact closed sets** in $X$ are closed in $X^*$. We have to prove that $C$ in $X^*$ is closed.

1. If it does not contain $\infty$, then it is compact in $X$. Then it is **compact and closed** in $X$, hence closed in $X^*$.
2. If it contains $\infty$, decompose it as $C'\cup\{\infty\}$. For any compact (hence closed) set $D$ in $X$ (hence in $X^*$), $C'\cap D=C\cap D$ is compact (closed subset of compact $C$). So $C'\cap D$ is closed in $X$, meaning $C'$ is closed by the **$k$-space property**. Then $C$ is closed in $X^*$ by definition.

---

It is interesting to note that $T_1<T_B<T_2$. $T_1$ is preserved in one-point compactification. $T_2$ is preserved iff $X$ is locally compact. $T_B$ is preserved if $X$ is a $k$-space. Locally compactness implies $k$-space: $x\notin X$ has a compact neighborhood $U$, and either $U\cap X=\emptyset$, or $U\cap X$ is closed, and then there is a further neighborhood $U'$ with $U'\cap X=\emptyset$.